# is there a difference between 1.71.0 and 1.74.0 when using boost :: bind

Tags: c++

No problem using boost 1.71.0 but when using 1.74.0 i get compile error, the code is the same

```
typedef boost::signal2::signal<void (int)> Signal;

Signal sig;

sig.connect(boost::bind(&connection::OnDataConnectionDone, this, _1);
```

The function looks like this

```
vod connection::OnDataConnection(int status) {

}

error: ‘_1’ was not declared in this scope
             sig.connect(boost::bind(&connection::OnDataConnectionDone, this, _1));
```

all help is appreciated
huvcbo

Comment: please post the real code ([mcve]). `vod` is obviously not the code you are compiling to get that error

Comment: did you include the necesarry headers? Sometimes headers do include other headers, so sometimes you get away with not including a header. This can easily break when you use a different version. Again, a mcve is needed

Comment: looks like something stopped `using namespace boost::placeholders;`

Answer (score 5):

Actually yes, there are certain changes in the new version. One of them is, bind placeholders in the global namespace is deprecated (since `v1.73.0`). If you enable warnings you may get something like this:

> The practice of declaring the Bind placeholders (_1, _2, ...) in the
> global namespace is deprecated. Please use <boost/bind/bind.hpp> +
> using namespace boost::placeholders, or define
> BOOST_BIND_GLOBAL_PLACEHOLDERS to retain the current behavior.

This is the warning it gives on using placeholders in `v1.74.0` with (`boost/bind.hpp`) [Ref.](https://godbolt.org/z/bEWY3P)

If you look properly into the [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html#bind.implementation.files) of the latest version, the main header has been changed from `boost/bind.hpp` to `boost/bind/bind.hpp`.

Since you haven't yet provided a minimum reproducible example, I can only guess that you have changed `boost/bind.hpp` to `boost/bind/bind.hpp`, but forgot to put `using namespace boost::placeholders;` before using `_1` in your code.

Comment: I Thank you so much,
now it works.